# Photos imported into Aperture aren't showing up — why not?

Tags: aperture, file-management

I imported about 500 images into Aperture (mostly CR2, but some jpg), and for some reason they're not showing up in my library.

If I right click on my library and select "Show Package Contents" and navigate to the Masters folder, I can find the images, but Aperture itself doesn't recognize them for some reason. I tried repairing the database, but that didn't solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'm feeling kind of stupid right now. So what had happened was I was importing photos from a range of dates, and some of them were back quite a ways, so it arranged the Event down the page, and since I wasn't looking for photos from the oldest day, I didn't recognize the Event.

But what also threw me off was that it created a blank "Untitled 1" Event at the top of my Events, for which  I still cant account.

I finally found the right event, and after dividing out the other days, it promptly jumped to it's rightful position as the most recently imported event.

Phew!